# arm-apple-darwin9-g++ Bus error problem

Tags: iphone, arm

I want to create a mobilesubstrate plugin for iPhone OS 3.2 or I tried to setup toolchain on the iPad device. 
I have installed the iphone-gcc_4.2-20090304-1-9_iphoneos-arm package and all the relevant packages from Cydia, but when it comes to compiling the simplest source file shows the following error:

```
arm-apple-darwin9-g++ -I /var/toolchain/sys/ -c -dynamiclib ExampleHookLibrary.mm -o ExampleHookLibrary.o
arm-apple-darwin9-g++: Internal error: Bus error (program cc1objplus)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <URL:http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter> for instructions.
make: *** [ExampleHookLibrary.o] Error 1
```

Is it because the iphone-gcc doesn't yet support this device or am I missing anything here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script automatically setup iphone toolchain for you, runs on Mac OS X, thanks to @rpetrich. http://gist.github.com/403608

First, remember to 
`apt-get remove iphone-gcc`
before running this thing on your mac, if you don't want to collect headers files from iphone sdk, follow the Darwin arm part of the script and I think you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Try iPhone 3.0 Toolchain from TheWorm repository (http://cydia.theworm.tw/), it works for me like a charm. You'll also need the headers from iOS SDK 3.0...3.2.2, and the binary frameworks (extensionless dylib's) also from the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Bus error is a different form of a segmentation fault. The toolchain is broken in some way.

Comment: maybe.. since the package is last update in 2009, maybe cross compiler is the only option left for me

Answer (score 0):

try "iphone 2.0 toolchain" form bigboss